# Does Joker have voice acting outside the main campaign?

Tags: batman-arkham-knight

About a month ago, I finished Batman: Arkham Knight on PC (the game was playable enough for me). I finished the story mode quite quickly, only having finished Hush and some partial missions before the final mission in the campaign.

After watching some scenes from streamers, it appears that I finished this story line too soon, however, because I saw some Joker voice acting near a Militia Watch tower that I think I missed.

The Joker voice acting in Knight, to me, was one of the highlights of the game, and I'm worried that I missed some of it. I was already planning on doing another playthrough of the game later this month, after the first major patch for PC so I can hopefully play the game in a more intended fashion. Is there Joker voice acting outside of the main storyline?

Comment: Well he always had some comments when I did the Riddler's challenges in orphanage (with Catwoman).

Comment: I see the headline of this question as a major spoiler, but I can't see a way to rephrase it so that it will get the answers it needs. Which in turn led me to look into Arqade's spoiler policy - which I don't see in the help anywhere. What should I do?

Comment: @PaulBrinkley I tried to fix it. I'm not sure if it made things better or worse though.

Comment: Thanks for trying. I see no change, though; is it in some sort of approval process? ...the main problem I see is that it mentions Joker. That might be out of spoiler territory by now, though - my main concern on *that* front is that many PC players might be waiting to buy AK, and can't, due to Rocksteady pulling it.

Comment: @PaulBrinkley I had the same concern. I edited the question, but Wipqozn  reverted the edit because a good question is better than a spoiler free question (as discussed in chat in the past 48 hours or so).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On my first play through I saved the final mission for last.  On the new game plus I rushed through it (mostly) and noticed quite a bit of differences.  During the Man-Bat missions, for instance, the Joker had some dialog in the lab (as well as scaring the poop out of me when I was randomly swinging from building to building, similar to how Man-Bat did).  As @Zikato mentioned, Joker would be outside the Riddler's mansion after his side missions as well.

Non-Joker related, there were also differences in dialog for the Hush side missions depending whether you had done the final main story mission or not.

There are probably too many to mention, but play new game plus the opposite way (save story missions for last as much as possible) and see for yourself!  You will be rewarded with more Joker dialog (which I agree with you, was very much a highlight).

Comment: I might do a NG+, but I'm a gamer that very much likes to take the path of least resistance, and NG+ seems to disable a number of mechanics I rely on, like counter icons. I might try it though.

Comment: I could only tell one difference during the intro with new game+ anyway, but I understand not wanting to run through it all again when you can just do another game that isn't NG+.